# What is this lizard-like thing?

Tags: animal-identification

This just crawled out of a houseplant I purchased last weekend. Can anyone help me identify it? I also need to know what to feed it because it probably hasn't eaten in a long time. It's about 4 inches long. The vendor's store is in Ottawa, Ontario, but they say their tropical plants are grown in greenhouses in Canada and the US.
[image]
[image]

Comment: To me it looks a bit like a brown anole which comes from Cuba

Comment: ...a **Florida female** brown anole according to an image on  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_anole). Apparently, you need to provide crickets, moths, ants, grasshoppers, cockroaches, mealworms, spiders, and waxworms.

Comment: Poor little girl from Florida ended up in Canada for the winter instead of the other way around! Thank you for identifying the specifics @WeatherVane! If you want to make a formal answer I'm happy to accept it because the photo of the Florida female is clearly right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP supposed the species to be **brown anole**, which I followed up with a visit to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_anole) and found a very similar image, with the caption

**Florida female**

[image]

<sub>*image from Wikipedia*</sub>

The article also identifies their diet.

Comment: Thank you. Though she'll be raised Canadian I'll make sure she knows where she came from :D